# Use the Laplace transform to solve the given integrodifferential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation, for which we must find $y(t)$.

$$y'(t) = 1 - \sin t - \int_{0}^{t} y(\tau) dx$$ with $y(0) = 0$.

I can do most Laplace transforms and most differential equations but somehow having them together is tripping me up.

Anything helps, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'(t)=-\int_0^t y(\tau ) \, d\tau -\sin (t)+1$$
$$s \left(\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)\right)-y(0)=-\frac{\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2+1}+\frac{1}{s}$$

$$s \left(\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)\right)=-\frac{\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)}{s}-\frac{1}{s^2+1}+\frac{1}{s}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)=\frac{s^2-s+1}{\left(s^2+1\right)^2}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}-\frac{s}{\left(s^2+1\right)^2}$$

$$y(t)=\sin (t)-\frac{1}{2} t \sin (t)$$

Comment: Hey, thanks so much!

Comment: @JohnSmith. I'm glad to help you.`:)`

Answer (score 1):

It might help to differentiate both sides to get a second-order ODE

$$ y''(t) = -\cos t - y(t) $$

with $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = 1$

Does this look like a nicer problem to solve?